# Add a column to mysql table in a rails application?

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, addition

I am developing a rails web application with mysql as my database. I had created table with 3 columns in it. I have already run the "rake db:migrate" command.

But now I need to add 2 more columns in the table. I tried to run this command:

> rails generate migration Add'col1'And'col2'To col1:integer col2:integer

It is creating a file in the `\db\migrate\` folder with following contents:

```
class Add<col1>And<col2>To<table_name> < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def change
    add_column :<table_name>, :<col1>, :integer
    add_column :<table_name>, :<col2>, :integer
  end
end
```

But when i go to mysql and look at the contents of my table, the columns are not added. 
How should i add the columns to an existing table?

Please Help.

Comment: You should read http://guides.rubyonrails.org/migrations.html. It'll answer your question.

Comment: can u show us the error log pls

Comment: yah sure, this is the error:

Comment: >rake db:migrate
==  CreateScribbles: migrating ============================
-- create_table(:scribbles)
rake aborted!
An error has occurred, all later migrations canceled:

Mysql2::Error: Table 'scribbles' already exists: CREATE TABLE `scribbles` (`id` int(11) DEFAULT NULL auto_increment PRIMARY KEY, `post` varchar(255), `posted_by` varchar(255), `posted_by_uid` varchar(255), `created_at` datetime NOT NULL, `updated_at` datetime NOT NULL) ENGINE=InnoDB
C:/Sites/railsprojects/socialbeam_latest/db/migrate/20130209055434_create_scribbles.rb:3:in `change'
C:in `migrate'
Tasks: TOP => db:migrate

Comment: i had one table scribbles, and 1 table users, i needed to add 2 columns to the table users.
now when i am runnin rake db:migrate, its giving that scribbles already exists

Comment: This might happen because you already have a migration that creates the table 'scribbles'. Because you don't have a timestamp set on that migration, is getting executed every time you run "rake db:migrate" and i'm guessing that is one of the first migrations and because fails all the other migrations are not executed.

Answer (score 1):

In addition to creating your migation, you need to run it, using `rake db:migrate`

Comment: I did run it, but its giving an error saying some other table already exists, and it cannot migrate

Answer (score 0):

http://guides.rubyonrails.org/migrations.html#migrations-are-classes

```
def change
     add_column :products, :part_number, :string
                 ^            ^              ^
                 table        column name    type
end
```

After defining the migration you need to run db:migrate again

Comment: i did it, but it is giving an error sayin some table already exists and it cannot migrate

Comment: This might happen because you already have a migration that creates the table 'scribbles'. Because you don't have a timestamp set on that migration, is getting executed every time you run "rake dm:migrate" and i'm guessing that is one of the first migrations and because fails all the other migrations are not executed.

Answer (score 0):

rails generate migration AddCol1AndCol2ToTable col1:integer col2:integer

raplace Table with Table name

Comment: yeah i have given table_name only

Comment: Run rake db:rollback to drop scribles table then run rake db:migrate

Answer (score 0):

Migrations are stored as files in your db/migrate directory, one for each migration class. The name of the file is of the form TIMESTAMP_create_products.rb, that is to say a UTC timestamp identifying the migration followed by an underscore followed by the name of the migration.  Rails uses this timestamp to determine which migration should be run and in what order, so if you're copying a migration from another application or generate a file yourself, be aware of its position in the order.

To add a specific column to your table in the database you should type the rails command

> > **rails generate migration addColumnToProducts column:type**

After that is done, you can do

> > **rake db:migrate**

Than you can see that you have added one new migration called:

TIMESTAMP_add_column_to_products.rb that has the following code:

```
class addColumnToProducts < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def change
    add_column :products, :column, :type
  end
end
```

And you have sucessfully added column to your database's table.

Answer (score 0):

so you wanna add new columns to your exist table .
you can do that by doing the following instruction using migration .

1 - `rails generate migration AddColumnToTableName`

2 -open up the migration file 
you will see

`AddColumnToTableName < ActiveRecord::Migration[5.0]
  def change
  end
end`

3 - inside `#change` function insert the new columns you need like that

```
 add_column :products, :part_number, :string
           (tablename) (coulmn name) (data type)
```

4- finally it should be like this

`class AddPartNumberToProducts < ActiveRecord::Migration[5.0]
  def change
    add_column :products, :part_number, :string
  end
end`

[wanna learn more about migration ?](http://edgeguides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_migrations.html)